# Visual studio bower.json out of sync with 'manage bower packages' window

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, bower

I've set my bower configuration file to use jquery version 3.1.1, however visual studio isn't reflecting this in the 'Manage Bower Packages...' context menu. When I right click on the bower file.

Version 2.2.3 is the highest version it will show.

**bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.6"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery-validation": "1.15.1",
    "jquery": ">=1.8"
  }
}
```

[image]

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I noticed the same issue, as far as I've been able to determine there are currently issues with both the Bower and NuGet package manager tools in VS2015.  Remember the VS2015 tooling for Asp.Net Core considered "preview" quality.

Comment: Okay that's fine as long as I'm not missing something. Is there a place to report such issues do you know?

Comment: I can't find the link, but it already has been entered in their issue tracker. I found it when running across this issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/575